# Understanding a JQuery complex chaining code example

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to understand the meaning of the $ sign when added to the beginning of a variable and why we have to wrap the **item** variable with the $ sign ? in order to change a text value.

For this line of code:

```
var $item = $(item);
```

> I think that $item is like any other variable ?

I have this short JQuery code:

```
var items = $('#special-features li');

items.width('50%')
    .height('200px')
    .addClass('hightlight bordered')
    .each(function(index, item){
        var $item = $(item);
        $item.text($item.text() + ' ' +
           $item.attr('data-features-id'));

});
```

Here is the result of the code above

[image]

Comment: People usually put a dollar sign as the first character of  variable that contains a jQuery wrapped object.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the question here is so I'll keep answering until I nail it. When you do $(...), you are simply calling a function. $ is actually an alias for jQuery, so you are actually calling a function called jQuery(...). This returns an object that jQuery wraps that corresponds to a group of DOM elements (it's an array) that you can then continue to call additional jQuery methods on. Putting $ in the variable name is simply a convention to let people know this is a jQuery object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is just **caching** the `$(item)` object. As it is used multiple times it's better practice to cache the object instead of referencing from DOM which will improve the performance slightly.

```
var $item = $(item);
$item.text($item.text() + ' ' +
   $item.attr('data-features-id'));
```

The `$` in `$item` is just a variable name. It is common practice to use `$` at the beginning of variable that contains jQuery object.

Comment: Why we can't directly access the text property of the parameter variable **item** of the function , like **item.text()...** ?

Comment: @HocineDJEMAI You can, but you also need to get the attribute value, so need to reference it again. Ex: `$item.text(function(i, oldText) { return  oldText + ' ' $item.data('features-id);});`

Answer (score 1):

`$` is a shorthand of the function `jQuery`. Since jQuery it's a simple javascript function, then when you call $() you just execute function and return the result to the variable and result of this function is jQuery object element.

`$` before variable names it's just convention how to higlight jQuery objects in the code.

And about chaining. In all methods in your example return value is the same object on what you apply this method. It's basically how chaining works.

Hope it answers all your questions.